# Why Python prints special characters @#$ etc. when I specifically said not to do so?

Tags: python, special-characters, alphanumeric

I'm trying to print the usernames that contain only letters, numbers, "-" and "_" and are between 3 and 16 characters long.

```
usernames = input().split(', ')

for word in usernames:
    if 3 <= len(word) <= 16 and (c for c in word if (c.isalnum() or c == '_' or c == '-')) and ' ' not in word:
        print(word)
```

Input:

```
Jeff, john45, ab, cd, peter-ivanov, @smith
```

Output must be:

```
Jeff
John45
peter-ivanov
```

But instead is:

```
Jeff
john45
peter-ivanov
@smith
```

Why is that so?

Comment: You're using a generator `(c for c in word if (c.isalnum() or c == '_' or c == '-'))` as a condition. It's not checking each item in the generator. The generator object is truthy, so your condition is true.

Comment: That expression generates a list containing all characters that match those criteria. It's Boolean value will be true if even one letter meets your criteria.

Comment: `all(True if (c.isalnum() or c == '_' or c == '-') else False for c in word )` Seeing as your current conditions have no way to return false for when invalid characters are in the word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(c for c in word if (c.isalnum() or c == '_' or c == '-'))` is a generator containing all those characters. All generators are truthy, so this is not actually checking anything.

Use the `all()` function to test if all the characters fit that criteria. And then there's no need to check `' ' not in word`, since that doesn't meet this criteria.

```
    if 3 <= len(word) <= 16 and all(c.isalnum() or c == '_' or c == '-' for c in word):
```

You could also also use a regular expression:

```
import re

for word in usernames:
    if re.match(r'[\w-]{3,}$', word):
        print(word)
```